# Dart Null Safety giving errors for typedef Function

Tags: dart

I have an example that [works in dart before null safety](https://dartpad.dev/1db58543201b511b7e27bfb191d1eef7) that doesn't after [upgrading to Null safety](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/1db58543201b511b7e27bfb191d1eef7). I can't figure out what's going on.

It gives me the error
A value of type 'dynamic Function()?' can't be returned from the method 'doSomething' because it has a return type of 'dynamic Function()'

But I didn't define anything as Nullable.

```
typedef RandomFunction = Function();

class RegisteredFunctions {
  Map<String, RandomFunction> types = {};

  static final RegisteredFunctions _registry = RegisteredFunctions._init();
  RegisteredFunctions._init() {}

  factory RegisteredFunctions() {
    return _registry;
  }

  void registerFunction(String name, RandomFunction func) {
    types[name] = func;
  }

  RandomFunction doSomething(String id) => types[id]; //<---- gives error
}

void doStuff(){
  print('Doing Something');
}

void main() {
  RegisteredFunctions functions = RegisteredFunctions();
  
  functions.registerFunction('func1', doStuff);
  functions.doSomething('func1')();
}
```

Comment: I figured it out.. casting the map to non nullable with the postfix ! fixed it. (ie: types[id]!)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to figure it out.. this fixed it.

```
typedef RandomFunction = Object? Function();

class RegisteredFunctions {
  Map<String, RandomFunction> types = {};

  static final RegisteredFunctions _registry = RegisteredFunctions._init();
  RegisteredFunctions._init() {}

  factory RegisteredFunctions() {
    return _registry;
  }

  void registerFunction(String name, RandomFunction func) {
    types[name] = func;
  }

  // RandomFunction doSomething(String id) => types[id];  // <----- Doesn't work
  
  // RandomFunction doSomething(String id) => types[id]!; // <----- Works
  
  RandomFunction doSomething(String id) {                 // <----- Works better
    RandomFunction? func = types[id];
    
    if (func != null) {
      return func;
    } else {
      return (){};
    }    
  }
}

void doStuff(){
  print('Doing Something');
}

void doOtherStuff(){
  print('Doing Something else');
}

void main() {
  RegisteredFunctions functions = RegisteredFunctions();
  
  functions.registerFunction('func1', doStuff);
  functions.registerFunction('func2', doOtherStuff);
  
  functions.doSomething('func1')();
  functions.doSomething('func2')();
}
```

Comment: Aaaaand... you just moved some possible edit-time errors into runtime errors.  Try never to do that.  Using ! is almost always a code-smell.

Comment: Another thing: don't use Function().  Spell it out, like Object? Function() if it really can be a function returning a nullable type with no args.

Comment: Thank you @Randal Schwartz. I've updated my DartPad example (linked above) with a cleaner solution.